# Save API data in Room database in Android

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-room

I want to take the data from API using retrofit and save them in room database. Then populate my Adapter, I added the data in Room but when the list with data shows to me when I click an element of the list of users I click to X user and it shows me the data for another user.  I haven't figured out where is my problem
Here is my code:

```
class TutorsFragment : Fragment(), TutorListAdapter.ListItemClickListener, fromBackgroundToMainUIThread {


private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var tutorListAdapter: TutorListAdapter? = null
private lateinit var tutors: List<Tutors>
private lateinit var tutorViewModel: StudentTutorViewModel

override fun onTutorsReceived(tutors: List<Tutors>) {
    this.tutors = tutors
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val tutorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutors, null)

    recyclerView = tutorView.findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerview_tutors) as RecyclerView
    tutorViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StudentTutorViewModel::class.java)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = layoutManager

    recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)

    tutorViewModel.getAllTutors().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            tutorListAdapter = TutorListAdapter(it as MutableList<Tutor>?, this@TutorsFragment)
            recyclerView!!.adapter = tutorListAdapter
        }
    })

    val api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().apiService
    val call = api!!.tutorsList

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Tutors>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Tutors>>, response: Response<List<Tutors>>) {

            Log.d("Tutors:  ", response.toString())
            val tutorsList = response.body()

            tutorsList!!.forEach {
                val tutor = Tutor(it.userID!!, it.name!!, it.lastname!!, it.email!!, it.roleFK!!, it.course!!.pathName)
                tutorViewModel.addTutor(tutor)
            }

            if (true) {
                this@TutorsFragment.onTutorsReceived(tutorsList)
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Tutors>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

    }

    val fab = tutorView.findViewById<View>(R.id.fab_tutors) as FloatingActionButton
    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val fragment = AddStudentAndTutorFragment()
        val title = "Add Tutors"
        val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
        val ft = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        ft.commit()

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.setTitle(title)
    }

    return tutorView
}

override fun onListItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {

    val tutor = tutors[position]
    val fragment = UserDetails()
    val title = "User Details"
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("name", tutor.name)
    bundle.putString("lastname", tutor.lastname)
    bundle.putString("email", tutor.email)
    bundle.putInt("userID", tutor.userID!!)
    bundle.putInt("role", tutor.roleFK!!)
    bundle.putString("course", tutor.course!!.pathName)
    fragment.arguments = bundle

    val fragmentManager = fragmentManager!!
    val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    ft.commit()

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.title = title

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val activity = activity as AppCompatActivity?
    val actionBar = activity!!.supportActionBar
    val my_fragment_title = "Tutors"
    actionBar!!.title = my_fragment_title
}
```

}

```
internal interface fromBackgroundToMainUIThread {
fun onTutorsReceived(tutors: List<Tutors>)
```

}

And Here is my Adapter class:

```
class TutorListAdapter(private val tutorsList: MutableList<Tutor>?, private val onItemClickListener: ListItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TutorListAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewtype: Int): ListViewHolder {

    return ListViewHolder(viewGroup.inflate(R.layout.list_item))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return tutorsList!!.size
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(listViewHolder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val tutors = tutorsList!![position]
    listViewHolder.listItemTextView.text = tutors.name + "  " + tutors.lastname
}

fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    if (position < 0 || position >= tutorsList!!.size) {
        return
    }

    tutorsList.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}

interface ListItemClickListener {

    fun onListItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
}

inner class ListViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    var listItemTextView: TextView

    init {

        listItemTextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.list_item_textview) as TextView
        view.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        onItemClickListener.onListItemClick(v, adapterPosition)
    }
}
```

}

ViewModel class:

```
class StudentTutorViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

var repository: Repository = Repository(application)

fun addTutor(tutor: Tutor) = repository.addTutor(tutor)

fun getAllTutors() = repository.getTutors()
```

}

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me

Comment: is it happening the very first time you click after loading the data on screen? or after removing or adding an item?

Comment: can you pls. post your ViewModel class.

Comment: It happens after adding an item @rafa

Comment: I just added ViewModel class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
The problem was that in onListItemClick function I call the list that is being populated from API not from Room
So this is the solution

I created a list variable that gets populated inside getAlltutors() function:

```
private lateinit var list: List<Tutor>

tutorViewModel.getAllTutors().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        list = it!!
        //rest of the code
    })
```

Then in OnListClickItem function :

```
 override fun onListItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {

    val tutor = list[position]    //line that changed
    val fragment = UserDetails()
    val title = "User Details"
    val bundle = Bundle()
    println("Name: " + tutor.name)
    bundle.putString("name", tutor.name)
    bundle.putString("lastname", tutor.lastname)
    bundle.putString("email", tutor.email)
    bundle.putInt("userID", tutor.userId)
    bundle.putInt("role", tutor.roleFk)
    bundle.putString("course", tutor.pathName)
    fragment.arguments = bundle

    val fragmentManager = fragmentManager!!
    val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    ft.commit()

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.title = title

}
```

Now it works

Answer (score 0):

the problem probably lies within the way you identify the data of the item that has been clicked in your list.
what i usually do is to pass the clicklistener as lambda function to the RecyclerAdapter
this way you can set the clicklistener on viewholder in onBindViewHolder
so this approach could be like this :

```
//in your ListAdapter class constructor instead of
class TutorListAdapter(private val tutorsList: MutableList<Tutor>?, private val onItemClickListener: ListItemClickListener)
//do like this
class TutorListAdapter(private val tutorsList: MutableList<Tutor>?, private val onItemClicked: (Tutor)->Unit)
```

```
//in your onBindViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(listViewHolder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
   listViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener{
      onItemClicked(tutorsList[position])
      //rest of your code
   }
}
```

```
//in your fragment when creating TutorListAdapter
tutorViewModel.getAllTutors().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            tutorListAdapter = TutorListAdapter(it as MutableList<Tutor>?, {tutor->
                    //you have the tutor object
                    //now do what ever you want
                })
            recyclerView!!.adapter = tutorListAdapter
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, below I already posted the solution